# Request body sometimes null

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda

The request body sometimes (less than 1% of the time) is null when pulled into lambda. I am processing on the order of 14,000 request bodies one at a time. Any request bodies erring out have to be handled manually. Why is the body randomly coming in null?

Sample code ran from prompt (node index):

```
const async = require('async');
const _ = require('lodash');
const moment = require('moment');
const Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
const fs = require('fs');

const input = require('./TestFull.json');

module.exports = () => {
    const filename = `./eventfulFails-${new moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD-HHmmss")}.json`;
    console.log('Start Time: ', new moment().format("HH:mm:ss"));

    let failedObjects = {
        events: [],
        venues: [],
        performers: []
    };

    async.parallel([
        async.apply(processVenues, input.venues, failedObjects),
        async.apply(processPerformers, input.performers, failedObjects)
    ], (lookupErr) => {
        if (lookupErr) {
            return console.error('Error processing venues and performers.', lookupErr);
        }
        console.log('Start Events: ', new moment().format("HH:mm:ss"));

        async.waterfall([
            async.apply(processEvents, input.events, failedObjects)
        ], (eventErr) => {
            if (eventErr) {
                console.log('Time of Failure: ', new moment().format("HH:mm:ss"));
                return console.error('Error processing events.', eventErr);
            }
            console.log('End Time: ', new moment().format("HH:mm:ss"));

            if (failedObjects.events.length || failedObjects.venues.length || failedObjects.performers.length) {
                const stream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
                stream.once('open', function(fd) {
                    stream.write(JSON.stringify(failedObjects));
                    stream.end();
                });
            }
        });
    });
};

function processVenues(venues, failedObjects, callback) {
    const calls = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < venues.length; i++) {
        const v = venues[i];

        calls.push(async.apply((venue, postCallback) => {
            const client = new Client();
            const args = {
                data: venue,
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
            };

            client.post('https://hm1br4yo34.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/eventful-venue', args, (data, response) => {
                if (response.statusCode !== 200 && response.statusCode !== 201) {
                    failedObjects.venues.push({
                        venue,
                        response
                    });
                    console.log('venue status code: ', response);
                    console.log('venue data: ', venue);
                }
                return postCallback(null);
            });
        }, v));
    }

    async.waterfall(calls, callback);
}

function processPerformers(performers, failedObjects, callback) {
    const calls = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < performers.length; i++) {
        const v = performers[i];

        calls.push(async.apply((performer, postCallback) => {
            const client = new Client();
            const args = {
                data: performer,
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
            };

            client.post('https://hm1br4yo34.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/eventful-performer', args, (data, response) => {
                if (response.statusCode !== 200 && response.statusCode !== 201) {
                    failedObjects.performers.push({
                        performer,
                        response
                    });
                    console.log('performer status code: ', response);
                    console.log('performer data: ', performer);
                }
                return postCallback(null);
            });
        }, v));
    }

    async.waterfall(calls, callback);
}

function processEvents(events, failedObjects, callback) {
    const calls = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        const v = events[i];

        calls.push(async.apply((event, postCallback) => {
            const client = new Client();
            const args = {
                data: event,
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
            };
            client.post('https://hm1br4yo34.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/eventful', args, (data, response) => {
                if (response.statusCode !== 200 && response.statusCode !== 201) {
                    failedObjects.events.push({
                        event,
                        response
                    });
                    console.log('event status code: ', response);
                    console.log('event data: ', event);
                }
                return postCallback(null);
            });
        }, v));
    }

    async.waterfall(calls, callback);
}

if (!module.parent) {
    module.exports();
}
```

Code of function processVenues (eventful-venue-load) that is called:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const async = require('async');
const sdk = require('@consultwithmikellc/withify-sdk');

const host = process.env.aurora_host;
const user = process.env.aurora_user;
const database = process.env.aurora_database;
let decryptedPassword;

const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
    region: 'us-west-2' //your region
});

class WithifyEventCreate extends sdk.Lambda {
    constructor(event, context, keysToDecrypt) {
        super(event, context, keysToDecrypt);

        this.getLocation = this.getLocation.bind(this);
        this.insertLocations = this.insertLocations.bind(this);
        this.insertLocationImages = this.insertLocationImages.bind(this);
    }

    decryptedKey(key, value) {
        switch (key) {
            case 'aurora_password':
                decryptedPassword = value;
                break;
        }
    }

    initializeComplete() {
        this.connect(host, user, decryptedPassword, database, true);
    }

    connectComplete() {
        async.waterfall(
            [
                this.getLocation,
                this.insertLocations,
                this.insertLocationImages
            ]
        );
    }

    getLocation(callback) {
        const {id: eventfulLocationID} = this.body;

        this.connection.query('SELECT * FROM `Location` WHERE `eventfulLocationID` = ?',
            [eventfulLocationID],
            (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                    // error call block
                    return this.sendResponse(err, this.createResponse(500));
                } else if (results.length === 1) {
                    console.log('Invoking withify-eventful-venue-update...');
                    lambda.invoke({
                        FunctionName: 'withify-eventful-venue-update',
                        Payload: JSON.stringify(this.event)
                    }, (error, data) => {
                        return this.sendResponse(null, JSON.parse(data.Payload));
                    });
                } else if (results.length > 1) {
                    return this.sendResponse(`The location lookup produced multiple results. event:${JSON.stringify(this.body)}`, this.createResponse(500));
                } else {
                    return callback(null);
                }
            }
        );
    }

    insertLocations(callback) {
        const {name: locationName, address: street, city, region_abbr: state, postal_code,
            description, id: eventfulLocationID, latitude: lat, longitude: lng, withdrawn: locationWithdrawn} = this.body;
        let addresses = street.concat(', ', city, ', ', state, ', ', postal_code);

        if (!description.length){
            var phones = "";
        }else{
            var re = /(([\(][0-9]{3}[\)][\s][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{4})|([0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{4})|([0-9]{3}[\.][0-9]{3}[\.][0-9]{4}))/i;
            this.body.found = description.match(re);

            if (!this.body.found){
                var phone = "";
            }else{
                if (!this.body.found.length){
                    var phone = "";
                }else{
                    var phone = this.body.found[0];
                }
            }
        }
        this.connection.query('INSERT IGNORE INTO `Location` (`locationName`, `address`, ' +
            '`phone`, `lat`, `lng`, `eventfulLocationID`, `locationWithdrawn`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
            [locationName, addresses, phone, lat, lng, eventfulLocationID, locationWithdrawn],
            (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                    return this.sendResponse(err, this.createResponse(500));
                }

                this.body.locationID = results.insertId;
                return callback(null);
            }
        );
    }

    insertLocationImages(callback) {
        var altText = "";
        const images = _.flatten(this.body.images.map(im => {
            return _.map(im.sizes, (ims, idx) => {
                const title = `Image ${idx}`;

                return [
                    this.body.locationID,
                    this.body.name,
                    ims.url,
                    null,
                    null,
                    this.body.id,
                    ims.width,
                    ims.height
                ];
            });
        }));
        if(!images[0]){
            return this.sendResponse(null, this.createResponse(201, this.body));
        }
        this.connection.query('INSERT IGNORE INTO `LocationImage` (`locationID`, `imageTitle`, `imageUrl`, ' +
            '`imageName`, `altText`, `eventfulLocationID`, `width`, `height`) VALUES ?',
            [images],
            (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                    return this.sendResponse(err, this.createResponse(500));
                } else if (results.affectedRows !== images.length) {
                    return this.sendResponse('The image inserts did not affect the right number' +
                        ' of rows.', this.createResponse(500));
                }

                return this.sendResponse(null, this.createResponse(201, this.body));
            }
        );
    }
}

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    const withifyEventCreate = new WithifyEventCreate(event, context, ['aurora_password']);
    withifyEventCreate.initialize([decryptedPassword]);
};
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you appear to be creating temporary files, and not cleaning them up.  With enough requests and the right timing of container reuse, you could be filling up your temp space.

Comment: The file being created only contains at most 5 JSON objects. Objects that have not been processed due to body being null.

Comment: Right, but you also mentioned 14,000 invocations, and the `/tmp/` space may not work like you think it does.